# Azure Function App IFunctionInvocationFilter loses Request body after Request executes

Tags: azure-functions, httprequest

I have a filter on an Azure Function that performs some tasks right after the the main function action has completed.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "notImportant")]
                HttpRequest req,
                ClaimsPrincipal principal)
            {
              string bodyContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();  //Always has content
            }
```

My Filter looks like this:

```
public class TraceAuditFilter : IFunctionInvocationFilter
    {
       

        public TraceAuditFilter()
        {
            
        }


        public async Task OnExecutedAsync(FunctionExecutedContext executedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
          var request = (HttpRequest)executedContext.Arguments["req"];
          string body = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd(); //Always Empty
        }
}
```

My filter sucessfully fires, but the 'body' in the filter method is always Empty. Any ideas what is resetting it?

Comment: 0


I found a similar problem and solution here: How to read request body in an asp.net core webapi controller? Using request.EnableBuffering() before I read the body and req.Body.Position = 0 to reset it to be read elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add the function filter class as an attribute.

That might be a reason as the filter is not being invoked in the functions.

You need to add `[TraceAuditFilter]` to the function so that the filter can be passed.

Refer the following articles for Indepth explanation: -
[IFunctionInvocationFilter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/do-you-know-azure-function-have-function-filters/)

[function filters](https://donotpanic.azurewebsites.net/2019/10/14/improve-azure-function-logging-with-function-filters/)